# Wordpress remove title from nav menu CustomTinyMce

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, title

The Wp theme does not show title on hover but adding CustomTinyMce display the description hovering on the menu item, how cai get rid of that?
Here is the code. Would like to do it with css if possible. Thanks

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-40 current-cat"><a h ref="http://foo.com/en/events/" title="Events &nbsp; lorem ipsum dolor sin...">Events</a> </li>
```